# Xamarin Forms ( iOS build) "Can't resolve the reference 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have hit a blocking error after upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 16.6.0 and subsequently upgraded Xamarin.IOS package to 13.4.

Here is the exact error message:
**Can't resolve the reference 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException', referenced from the method 'System.Void System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException::.ctor(System.String,System.Exception,System.String,System.Int32)' in 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   HSETicketingMobile.iOS**

The app used to build successfully before the upgrade. Is there anything I can do or is it a newly introduced upgrade issue and I have to wait for the fix from Microsoft?

I tried to google the error but I couldn't find any solution.

My visual studio is on Windows and I'm connecting to XCode over the LAN.
Thank you

Here is my build log:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZwwIZVwWZdge0uleZyPDySfhHczHuXOI

Comment: Can you please try to set the linker behavior to Link Frameworks SDKs Only and build again?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tried your suggestion but I received the same result. I'm using Syncfusion and appcenter crash and analystics libraries in the app. Could be the source of the error?

Comment: Have you updated them to the latest version?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes I did update to the latest version for all Nuget packages. **I added the build log to the original post.** Sorry I should've done that earlier. Thanks

Comment: Can you please try delete the bin/obj folder under all projects and then clean/rebuild your project again?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I did. But I still have the same problem

Comment: Well, not much idea about the issue. There maybe some conflict between nuget packages.  You can open a [free Xamarin ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6%5D) for more help if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the source of the problem.

I was including System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in one of my modules and it was in turn calling System.Configuration.ConfigurationException under the hood.

I added a build condition to exclude the use of the DataAnnotations for my Xamarin.iOS and that solved the problem.

The strange thing is that my code hasn't changed and just upgrading to VS 2019 16.6.0 caused the problem to happen.

I got a hint from this discussion thread [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88748/unable-to-deploy-to-ios-device-failed-to-resolve-system-configuration-configurationexception)

I hope this helps someone else.